# How to visualize tf.contrib.distribution.MultivariateNormalDiag?

Tags: tensorflow

I have constructed a Variational Auto-Encoder which has the latent distribution as a Multivariate Normal distribution. I want to store the distribution and visualize it (in tensorboard or other software). However, when I try to use `add_summary` from `FileWriter` I am getting an error - `MultivariateNormalDiag object has no attribute 'value'`. How do I store and display the Gaussian distribution?
The code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tfd = tf.contrib.distribution

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 9])
x = tf.layers.dense(input,200, tf.nn.relu)
x = tf.layers.dense(x,200,tf.nn.relu)
loc = tf.layers.dense(x,1)
scale = tf.layers.dense(x,1,tf.nn.softplus)
latent = tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag(loc,scale)
# getting loss and minimizing it
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/tmp/dist")
writer.add_summary(latent) # Error over here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass a `tf.Summary` to `writer.add_summary()`.
Instead, you are passing a `tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag`, which does not have a `value` field.

Exctract the value that you want to write from `tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag` and create a [new](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Summary) `tf.Summary` with that value. Then pass it to `writer.add_summary()`

Consult more [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter)

Comment: So in order to visualize do I need to get the mean and variance to construct a normal distribution in a way that can be read in tf.Summary?

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. Extract the mean and variance scalars and write them out using writer.add_summary(). Then you can create a plot of the corresponding normal distribution.